# Using easymock, repeated void method call

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am new to easymock.

I am trying to mock a service where one of the methods is a void method that will get called an unknown (and large) number of times. How do I specify that any number of calls is allowed?

I know how to do it for methods that have a non-void return type.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Call the void method of the mock. Afterwards use `EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes()`

Comment: Probably better to use EasyMock.expectLastCall().atLeastOnce(), just to make sure the method is actually called.  I tend to use for all expectations because it makes your tests less brittle to internal changes that don't effect behavior.